# reading string from Golang map

Tags: go

I am starting in Golang. Currently I want to get the string that is stored to the key `key_field` from this map:

```
map[key_field:[76 95 76 105 115 116 105 110 103 73 68]]
```

this map is declared as:

```
map:= make([]map[string]interface{}, 0)
```

What I want is to store in a string the value contained in that byte array, that values I printed them using `fmt.Println`
Thank you so much

Comment: I'm confused about what you're trying to do. For one thing, that `make` is going to make a slice of maps, which I don't think is what you want (is it)? What are you trying to map from/to? Why are you using `interface{}` as the element type in your map?

Comment: @fstanis I didnt make it, its a previous code that left other developer. It's the result of a query to a database and there is only retrieved a column (the one that I'm trying to get the data)

Comment: If you know the value is byte slice then you can do type assertion and byte slice to string. For e.g.: `string(mymap["key_field"].([]byte))`

Comment: @SrednyMCasanova possible that you are reading a byte array instead of string try string(value) or value.(string)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to store a string inside map declare the map as

```
values:= []map[string]string{}
```

so reading it will be easier, but for some reasons you need a map of interfaces then

```
values := []map[string]interface{}{}
```

Now to read a value from this map

```
fmt.Println(values[index]["key"])
```

Example:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    strMap := map[string]interface{}{
        "hello": "world",
    }
    val := []map[string]interface{}{}
    val = append(val, strMap)
    fmt.Println(val[0]["hello"])
}
```

Playground link:

https://play.golang.org/p/ptWuVy64pk

Answer (score 0):

`map[key_field]`  is interface{}, so that you must use type assertion inorder to get right type of it([]byte).

here you are:

```
    if needString,ok := map[key_field].([]byte); ok {
      fmt.Println(string(needString))
    }
```